# Timedelta unsupported days component | python 2.7

Tags: python, datetime, dictionary, timedelta

I am extracting timetamp from dictionary and then converting it into time-format.
When I try to compare with `datetime.datetime.now()` using time delta it gets error:

```
dict={'Username': 'abc', 'Timestamp': '5/17/2017 16:52:35', 'GroupName': 'Cpositive'}

dictime=dict["Timestamp"]
dictime = datetime.datetime.strptime(dictime, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')
print(dictime)
finaltime=(datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(dictime))
print(finaltime)
```

output:

```
TypeError: unsupported type for timedelta days component: datetime.datetime
```

Comment: `datetime.timedelta(dictime)` makes no sense, you can't use a datetime as argument of a timedelta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, you want this, when you subtract 2 datetimes the result is timedelta:

```
>>> dictime = datetime.datetime.strptime(dictime, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')
>>> finaltime=(datetime.datetime.now() - dictime)
>>> finaltime.days
0
>>> finaltime.seconds
1379
>>>
```